# Unable to fetch the group list from the Azure Active Directory through Enterprise App

Tags: ldap, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We are trying to integrate the Azure Active Directory **(using Graph API)** with java web-based custom LDAP application to sync groups. As a first step, we can authenticate and get tokens, but facing error

> Authorization_IdentityNotFound, the identity of the calling application could not be established, Request ID: cec7a25c-0af6-4c6a-99f714d80a01ad85

while trying to fetch the groups using graph API URL from Azure AD site.

Steps done for Azure AD Configuration:

1. Created app using “App Registration” in Azure Active Directory (From here we have taken application id (client id), tenant id- Used same in JAVA Application for integration).
2. Configured API Permission from the Azure active directory graph:
   a. Application Permission – Provided read access to Application, Directory, Domain, Member & Policy
   b. Delegated Permission –  Provided read access to Directory, Member, Policy, Groups, and Users
3. Generated client secret key for the registered App.
4. Created users and groups – (Added users into the groups)
5. Graph API - `https://graph.windows.net` (This link used in application)
6. Active directory authority - `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/` (This link used in application)

What other configuration/permission level required to fetch Group List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error in your question, I guess you should be using the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), which generally uses application permissions. For this error, you only need to change the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/` Replace `common/` with `tenant Id` or `domain name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Carl. After changing the URL to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/<tenant id> and it got worked.